# Can you use Map when transpiling Typescript to Google Script?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

I'm trying to use `clasp` according to official recommendations. 
This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

This is the example code I'm trying to push to Google Apps Script project using `clasp push`:

```
function test(): string {
  const m: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
  m.set("foo", "bar");
  return JSON.stringify(m);
}
```

This is how it gets transpiled:

```
// Compiled using ts2gas 1.6.2 (TypeScript 3.5.2)
var exports = exports || {};
var module = module || { exports: exports };
function test() {
    var m = new Map();
    m.set("foo", "bar");
    return JSON.stringify(m);
}
```

When running the method on Google Apps Script project, I'm getting an error:
`ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined. (line 5, file "test")`

According to my understanding, Google Apps Script should provide `Map` since it's a part of `esnext`. What am I doing wrong? Why is `Map` not available?

Comment: `lib` is how you tell the compiler what libraries are available in your runtime; it doesn't mean that your transpiled code will *add* those libraries.  If those libraries are not already present you'll have to polyfill them.

Comment: @jcalz my understanding was that if `clasp` authors suggested `esnext`, it would mean an appropriate `lib` is already polyfilled by default. how should I include an actual implementation of, say, `Map`, in my current setup?

Comment: I don't really know anything about clasp... Not sure there's an official answer to your question other than "find an ES3/ES5 polyfill for `Map`".  There is a relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/609) about this, though, where they mention [this script](https://github.com/brucemcpherson/cEs6Shim/blob/master/Code.gs).

Comment: Really though if your keys are just `string`s, I'd probably want to use a plain JS dictionary object (`var m: {[k: string]: string | undefined} = {}; v.foo = "bar"; return JSON.stringify(m)`) instead of `Map` even if `Map` were present in the runtime.  Not sure what a `string`-keyed `Map` buys you.

Comment: @jcalz this was just a minimal case that displayed that Map's missing. I'm actually using it properly elsewhere. thanks for the Github issue and the proposed script, it seems like I'll have to do it that way. it's just.. I was (and still am) surprised that the suggested dev env for `clasp` doesn't match the env that's running in Apps Script. it makes it harder to develop things locally.

Comment: Related note: for Typescript transpiling, Clasp relies completely on [ts2gas](https://github.com/grant/ts2gas) under the hood (as noted in the auto generated code comment). In the readme for that, it specifically states that the tsconfig default target for ts2gas is `es3`, and it cannot be changed.